# Transform integer column to date

Tags: r, date

I have a column in format 19990101 that I would like to change to date format. It is currently as integer.

I've tried the following but it results in

> Error: unexpected symbol in: mutate(Date = Date, Date = as.integer(format)date.

```
mutate(Date = Date,
       Date = as.integer(format)date, "%Y%m%d")
```

Comment: `as.Date(format(x), "%Y%m%d")`

Comment: or `library(lubridate)
ymd(Date)`

Answer (score 0):

```
mutate(Date = Date,
       Date = as.Date(format(x), "%Y%m%d")
```

The above code solved my issue.